# How to change double qoutes to single qoutes for child objects in JSON?

Tags: json, linux, bash, transform, jq

I have a JSON text files and I need to import it into a database. I have prepared it well except for a minute difference ie I need to change the double qoutes to single qoutes for all nested level children/values of JSON using jq.

For example,

```json
{"foo":"bar","ping":{"pong":"ping-pong","n":[{"a":1},{"b":2}]},"alpha":"beta","hello":"there!","you":"2"}
```

and expected output is:

```json
{"foo":"bar","ping":{'pong':'ping-pong','n':[{'a':1},{'b':2}]}, "alpha":"beta","hello":"there!","you":"2"}
```

Comment: `I need to` that's a very, very odd requirement. Why not just import it to the database instead of changing quotes? Are you asking XY question?

Comment: The database I require is failing to import without following this structure. I need to dump JSON or JSON array as one big string in it and using nested double qoutes gives parsing errors while importing.

Comment: From [json.org](https://www.json.org/json-en.html): "A *string* is a sequence of zero or more Unicode characters, wrapped in double quotes, using backslash escapes.". This means, your strings should keep the double quotes around them, and if you need a double quote character as (part of) a value, escape it with a backslah: `\"`. For example, this is `"a \"valid\" string"`

Answer (score 0):

To turn any JSON object into a JSON-encoded string use jq's `tojson` or `@json` functions:

```bash
jq '.ping |= tojson' example.json
```

[Demo](https://jqplay.org/s/t67i4J3zoG7)

```bash
jq '.ping |= @json' example.json
```

[Demo](https://jqplay.org/s/wTHBV-ESehy)

Both produce

```json
{
  "foo": "bar",
  "ping": "{\"pong\":\"ping-pong\",\"n\":[{\"a\":1},{\"b\":2}]}",
  "alpha": "beta",
  "hello": "there!",
  "you": "2"
}
```

Comment: Just need to change values for root keys and within values only nested objects or arrays of nested objects.